# Cannot Find Name Long

Tags: javascript, angular, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I am trying to design software on angular that guess the correct written word correctly using tensorflow.js with angular

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

linearModel?: tf.Sequential;
prediction: any;



  ngOnInit(){
    // this.trainNewModel();

   }
//   async trainNewModel(){

//     this.linearModel = tf.sequential();

//     this.linearModel.add(tf.layers.dense({
//       units: 1,
//       inputShape:[1]
//     }));

//     this.linearModel.compile({
//       loss: 'meanSquareError',
//       optimizer: 'sgd'
//     });


//     const xs = tf.tensor1d([3.2,4.4,5.5,6.71,6.98,7.168,9.779,7.59,2.16]);
//     const ys = tf.tensor1d([1.6,2.7,2.9,3.19,1.684,2.53,3.366,2.596,2.53,1.22]);

//     await this.linearModel.fit(xs,ys);


//     console.log('model trained!');


//   }


// linearPrediction(val:any){
//   const output = this.linearModel.predict(tf.tensor2d([val], [1, 1])) as any;
//   this.prediction = Array.from(output.dataSync())[0]
// }


 }
```

app.component.html

```
<!--
<h4> preicted value: {{ prediction }}</h4>

<input type = "number" (change)= "linearPrediction()"> -->
```

the error looks like this

```
ERROR

node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/hash_util.d.ts:2:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

2 export declare function hexToLong(hex: string): Long;
                                                  ~~~
```

I couldn't find the right documentation that clearly state the usage of tensorflow.js on angular; could anyone please show me?

Answer (score 7):

Nothing to do with AngularJS, its due to TypeScript strict type checks being enabled globally in your project for all dependencies, not just your code

And this is a known issue - TFJS is written using old TS 3.x and typedefs are not fully up to par

Best suggestion is to disable type checks on items inside TFJS by setting `skipLibCheck=true` in your `tsconfig.json`

But if you really want to use type checks on TS, good luck - and you'll need to include `long@4.0.0` as a dependency in your app (newest version `long@5.x` is NOT compatible)

Comment: inside `tsconfig.json` file  add `compilerOptions > skipLibCheck = true`.